# How to access portions of a N-D array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

So I have this 24403x90x3 array in Python. How can I print the first row, but only get all 90, but only choose the first depth out of three.

In Matlab it would just be:

```
A(1, :, 1)
```

Comment: Is it a `numpy.array`?

Comment: Python has lists, not arrays.  NumPy is the most common array provider.  What do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python allows for almost the same syntax. However, in Python indexing starts at zero, and, you use brackets instead of parentheses, giving you:

```
A[0,:,0]
```

(where I have assumed `A` to be a `numpy.array`)